# Good Wecam recording software

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam

I've tried the Cheese one already, but it lags. What are some other wecam recording software that doesn't lag? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this [WXCAM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxcam/) , I heard this is also one of the good software to get the webcam recording .